# Group several docker images into one image and have them communicate

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I come to you because I have a problem that I do not even know where to start to solve it.

Indeed, I have 3 images dockers who must communicate with each other.

An image for the **frontend** that must communicate with the image of the **backend** which must also communicate with the image of my **database** (MySQL).

And when I type http://localhost: 9090, I would like to access my **frontend** which should communicate with the **backend** that has to answer me by interacting with the **database**.

I looked at the docker-compose doc but they explain that the docker-compose keywords without an example showing how to solve the kind of my problem.

If you have good tutorials or blogs or code showing how to solve my problem, please help me.

Comment: Have you look at this? https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-3-define-services-in-a-compose-file

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a docker-compose.yml to do this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  database:
    image: <image>:<tag>
    container_name: database
    restart: unless-stopped

  backend:
    image: <image>:<tag>
    container_name: backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    links:
      - database

  frontend:
    image: <image>:<tag>
    container_name: frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "9090:9090" # the first port is what your app listens on
```

Then run `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I tested your solution it worked but it was necessary that I expose all the ports of the image backend and database like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  database:
    image: data
    container_name: database
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  backend:
    image: backend
    container_name: backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - database
    ports:
      - "8090:8090" 
      - "8091:8091"
      - "8092:8092"  
  frontend:
    image: frontend
    container_name: frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

and if I type a url backend, for example localhost: 8090 in the browser, this url answer me while I want to pass necessarily by the front to access the backend.

So for me the idea is that the ports of the backend and the database can only be visible inside the docker-compose.But I do not know how to do that with docker-compose

Thank you in advance for your help.